# Partial Lock for BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity , that initiates an IntentService to get some work done . When the work is done , the IntentService broadcast's and announces success.

The broadcast receiver is inside the same activity that initiates the IntentService.

The psuedo of this situation

```
    Activity A
{

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
          {
           //handle
          }
    } 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //initiate IntentService
    }
}
IntentService
{
    //Launch spaceshuttle . and broadcast success
}
```

Now what happens is that sometimes the launching the spaceshuttle takes some times , and the cellphone goes to sleep. As a result of which the broadcast receiver i believe needs to acquire a partial lock perhaps as far as I understand .

But the exact technique to do so has been evading me .

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solutions are either for you to:

- Use [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), or
- Use [the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) from the Android Support package

Both will manage the `WakeLock` for you. My `WakefulIntentService` is probably a more natural fit for the code as you have shown it, but both should work.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion . However upon reviewing the WakefulBroadcastReceiver I found out that it doesn't fit on my situation . Because WakefulBroadcastReceiver would only work if i fire an IntentService using startWakefulService from inside of it . In my case  , my activity fires the IntentService . As for WakeFulIntentService , I will look into it now